# Can someone explain how to do the change of variables in a linear programming problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

If I want to convert the following linear problem into a standard form:
$$\min z=4x_1+2x_2+x_3$$
Subject to
$$-x_1+3x_2-x_3\ge1$$
$$5x_1+3x_3=5$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3\le1$$
$$-1\le x_1, x_2\le2,x_3\ge0$$
I understand how to turn $\min z$ into $\max z$ and how to use the slack variables. What I don't get is how to do the change of variables for the constraints. In the answer I am suppose to introduce the variable $x_1'=x_1-1$, $x_2'=-x_2-2$. Why do we write it like this? What is the logic behind it? And what if the constraint is with the absolute value like: $|x_1|\le1$?

Comment: Presumably your standard form requires all variables to have $x_{I} >= 0$.  The substitutions you’ve listed accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the first comment, in the standard form, you have nonnegative decision variables. $\require{extpfeil} \Newextarrow{\xiff}{5,5}{0x21d4}$

\begin{alignat}{3}
-1 &\le x_1 &\iff x_1 + 1 &\ge 0 &\quad \xiff[]{\large \text{set } x_1'=x_1+1} \quad x_1' &\ge 0 \\
x_2 &\le 2 &\iff -x_2 + 2 &\ge 0 &\quad \xiff[]{\large \text{set } x_2'=-x_2+2} \quad x_2' &\ge 0
\end{alignat}

If you have $|x_1| \le 1$, you have to split it into two inequalities and include them in the constraints in the *canonical* form.

$$|x_1| \le 1 \iff
\begin{cases}
x_1 &\le 1 \\
-x_1 &\le 1
\end{cases}
$$